# python to exe convert part of the code

Tags: exe, py2exe, python-2.x

Very good, anyone know if I can make exe single piece of code in a script, for example:

one file (hello.py):

```
print('hello word')

def exit():
    print('good bye')
```

two file (setup.py):

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import sys
import hello


if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    sys.argv.append("py2exe")
    sys.argv.append("-q")


options = {
    #"bundle_files": 1,
    "dll_excludes": ["w9xpopen.exe"] # we don't need this
    }

setup(name = "python",
    description = "aplicacion python",
    version = "1.0",
    console = [
        {
            "script":"hello.exit()",
            #"icon_resources": [(0, "res_python.ico")]
        }
    ],
    options = {"py2exe": options},
    zipfile = None,

    )
```

for a better explanation, I create the exe from the same file, thanks.

Comment: What is your questions? Anything going wrong? Any error messages?

Comment: not leave any error message, but dist folder appears empty, no exe is created and notice in this line: "script":"hello.exit()",

Comment: Please show your command for executing `setup.py`. Please show the notice.

Comment: Here below is the code, the only shell instance calls a function, I just want to convert exe that function.

Answer (score 0):

Python used to be used before solid snake hd was implemented try corrupting the python file.